# Interface Listener C# without subscribing

Tags: c#, events, interface, listener

I have been using a lot of APIs where to listen to some event I just need to implement an interface, but it doesn't require me to subscribe, how they do that?

To explain it better here is how I usually do my listeners

```cs
interface IListener
{
    void OnEventHappen();
}

public class EventClass
{
     public static Action onEvent;
}

public class ListenerClass : IListener
{
    //constructor
    public ListenerClass()
    {
         EventClass.onEvent += OnEventHappen;
    }

    //function from IListener interface
    public void OnEventHappen() { //something... }
}
```

but in those APIs it is not necessary to subscribe anywhere, I just need to implement the interface like this: (I removed the EventClass because in those APIs I have no access to the classes who trigger the events)

```cs
interface IListener
{
    void OnEventHappen();
}

public class ListenerClass : IListener
{
    //function from IListener interface
    public void OnEventHappen() { //something... }
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question about?

Comment: Can you name one of those API's so we can know what we are facing? What comes to mind is, that they probably traverse all the assemblies and look for types implementing IListener and create an instance and call it.

Comment: The best way to see how your concrete class is "registered magically" may be to put a breakpoint in your constructor and see the call stack.

Comment: One example (not an API) would be in Unity, to use the IBeginDragHandler I just need to use EventSystems and implement the method OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)

Comment: Unity uses a *lot* of reflection. It does all kinds of things that aren't really idiomatic C# or .NET outside Unity. Your question says you've been using "a lot of APIs" which do this automatically - could you provide any examples of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c# such behavior can be achieved using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection).

One example in comments mentions Unity and it's methods like `OnBeginDrag` or `Update`. Those are not called using c# `events`. Unity is mostly written in c++ and after your c# code is compiled Unity looks for all classes implementing certain interfaces or inheriting from certain classes (like `MonoBehaviour`) and checks if they have matching methods (like `Update()`) so it can call them later when necessary.

Another comment mentions Photon, a networking engine commonly used with Unity. In this case there is no "magic" or even reflection. To receive Photon's callbacks you have to call `PhotonNetwork.AddCallbackTarget` method and pass instance of your class as an argument. Only confusing thing in case of Photon is fact, that you don't have to do that directly. Instead of calling this method yourself, you can just inherit from `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks` class which implements all Photon's callback interfaces and calls `PhotonNetwork.AddCallbackTarget` in it's `OnEnable` method. That method is in turn called by Unity like I explained earlier.

Comment: Is there a way to replicate this? Photon (networking framework for unity) for example has the IPunObservable which have the same behaviour

Comment: I guess by making it more user friendly they also made it harder to understand how things work behind the curtains. Thank you!